# Problem of projection with overlaying layers (GeoServer) on map (OSM) using Leaflet

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, leaflet, wms

I'm working on a web mapping application using GeoServer and Leaflet, the problem I have is when I overlay the WMS layer (loaded from GeoServer) on base map I do not have superposition.

This is my code:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
            layers: [OpenStreetMap], /// fond de base
            center: [30.412647, -9.579837],/// coordonnées
            zoom: 13    //// zoom par defaut
});


/////layers de base     
var baseLayers = {
        "Open Street Map": OpenStreetMap,
        "World Imagery": WorldImagery
};


var dist_layer = L.tileLayer.wms("http://192.168.250.198:8082/geoserver/test_layer/wms", {
        layers: 'test_layer:Districts_Agadir',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        version: '1.1.0',
        attribution: "myattribution"
});
```

The result I get:

[image]

---

This is my problem exactly the layer does not match base map

[image]

My layer is a shapefile created using ArcGIS 10.2 with Projection:

```
Projected Coordinate System:    Sud_Maroc_Degree
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  500000,00000000
False_Northing: 300000,00000000
Central_Meridian:   -5,40000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    29,70000000
Scale_Factor:   0,99961560
Latitude_Of_Origin: 29,70000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_Merchich_Degree
Datum:  D_Merchich
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

This is how my layer looks in ArcGIS it matches the base map exactly, and that's what I'm looking for in my web mapping application.

[image]

Comment: that looks about right, is there some reason to expect your data to match OSM exactly?

Comment: I have a problem of superposition, my layer doesn't match the base map exacltly

Comment: where does your data come from? why do you believe that it will match exactly

Comment: overlay layers are shapefiles configured in geoserver with SRC:EPSG :26192

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it, but you likely need a transformation to convert between Merchich and WGS84. EPSG:1166 or if you can use PROJ.4 strings, add this to the 26192 definition: +towgs84=31.0,146.0,47.0

Comment: I tried to convert the projection using this code : ' var crss = new L.CRS('EPSG:26192',
  '+proj=lcc +lat_1=29.7 +lat_0=29.7 +lon_0=-5.4 +k_0=0.9996155960000001 +x_0=500000 +y_0=300000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=31,146,47,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs',
  {
    resolutions: [
      8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128
    ],
    origin: [0, 0]
  });' but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a datum shift issue, but it looks GeoServer is already using the TOWGS84 parameters suggested in the comments, e.g.:

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.SRSDescriptionPage?code=EPSG:26192

Maybe check what yours is doing. 
In case you need to force a different set of TOWGS84 parameters you can follow this guide:

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/crshandling/customcrs.html#override-an-official-epsg-code

Comment: I created epsg_overrides.properties file and i added 26192 definition,but i don't know how to change TOWGS84 parameters and what i have to change exactly in datum code.Thank you

Comment: I found the solution for my problem. I created my shapefile with WGS84 projection and that's it.Thanks for everyone